# Cor no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cores

Olá!

Por acaso alguém sabe como posso trocar as cores **dos métodos/eventos não utilizados vs aqueles utilizados** no Visual Studio?

Tenho aqui o VS2013 (usando tema Dark) e o Resharper mas não consigo ver com exatidão os métodos/eventos de cada objeto/controle na combobox de METODOS/EVENTOS (aquela que aparece no topo à direita do editor, ao lado da a combo "CLASS NAME"), em relação aos eventos usados (branco hilite) e os não usados (também branco 95% hilite).

O que seria interessante? Por exemplo, os métodos/eventos não utilizados aparecerem em cinza ou algo assim, destacando logo aqueles em uso em determinado controle.

Alguém tem alguma dica para isso?
Muito agradecido por seu tempo e paciência.